# How to examine parameters in an ActionListener?

Tags: java, jbutton, actionlistener

I am currently working on a project which requires me to use JButtons to bring up dialogue boxes. Specifically, I need to bring up dialogue boxes which say that the player pressed a particular button and that it is now toggled (or has been un-toggled).

In order to do this, I need to examine the parameters of the button, specifically what the text contained in the button is. Here is my code.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)    //this creates 7 buttons, each with a different lable
{
    JButton category = new JButton();
    //dimensions are set here.
    switch(i)    
    {
        case 0:
            category.setText(Constants.TRIPLE);    //TRIPLE is a string constant
            category.addActionListener(new LowerSectionListener());
            break;
        //6 more cases follow, all similar to this one but with different constants
```

The action listener I call for each case is called LowerSectionListener. I want to be able to use one listener for all of these cases in order to optimize this class. My professor has suggested to me that I make a case system similar to the one I utilize for setting up these JButtons, but I don't know how I would go about doing that. May I have some advice? I believe there is a way to check for what text is in the category but I do not know it.

**EDIT**: My question apparently has been asked before, but referencing the previously answered question did not help me. It was suggested to use

```
System.out.println(ActionEvent.getActionCommand());
```

But that gave me an error. Apparently this method that I am using is a static method, and getActionCommand is non-static. What can I do to fix my problem? Do I need to entirely rewrite my code?

Comment: `ActionEvent` will pass you a bunch of values, one is the `source` of the object which triggered the event, another is the `actionCommand`, which is set by the source of the action.  In your case, the default `actionCommand` is actually the text of the button.  Have a closer look at [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for more details

Comment: It's not `ActionEvent.getActionCommand()`, it's `actionEvent.getActionCommand()` or `e.getActionCommand()`, or whatever your `ActionEvent` variable is named.